# Rails restrict wildcard route to certain format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiondispatch

I have a wildcard route in my `routes.rb` file:

```
get "*client" => "client#show"
```

In the controller, I look up the client in the database and display their custom page:

```
def show
  @client = Client.find_by(slug: params[:client])

  if @client.nil?
    render file: "client/404", layout: "error", status: :not_found
    return
  end
end
```

This works great, but my problem is that any asset that is not found is also being routed through my `client#show` handler.

This results in a pointless lookup in the database for a client and then I get a 500 error because Rails doesn't know how to render my error page for non-html formats.

My question is: **How can I prevent non-HTML formats from going into my wildcard handler?**

I've tried the following to no avail:

**Format Constraint**

Putting a scope around the route to constrain it to the HTML format:

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'html' } do
  get "*client" => "client#show"
end
```

This does keep assets from being routed to my handler, but unfortunately only routes pages to the handler if they explicitly end with the `.html` extension. Failure.

**Format Default**

Next, I thought I'd try a format *default*. Like so:

```
get "*client" => "client#show", :defaults => { :format => 'html' }
```

Unfortunately, still no workee. There is no change. My understanding is that this just sets the default format if Rails can't otherwise figure it out from the content-type header or file extension.

I'm starting to think there may not be a way to do this at the route level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't figure out how to restrict assets from going into my handler at the `route` level, I just put a check at the beginning of my handler to short-circuit the handler if the request is not HTML format.

```
def show
  render nothing: true, status: :not_found and return if invalid_format?
  ...
end

private

def invalid_format?
  request.format != "html"
end
```

Comment: Ruby < 2.2? Do not convert unknown inputs to symbols, or your app would be exposed to DoS out-of-memory attacks (requesting multiple formats in this case); instead use `request.format != 'html'`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this and put it before the `get "*client" => "client#show"` route:

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'example' } do
  get "*client" => "error#404"
end
```

Set the formats that you want to catch that would later match the general `get '*client'` and handle what to do with them before they get there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would prefer, though, not to have to make a route for al of the possible formats.